# Add color on parts of the text of an html button

Tags: html, css, button

I have a bunch of hmtl buttons, some have a value like: "Title*" I would like the star to be colored red while the rest of the text is black. Is this possible?

I found this code suggestions to make the text colored:

```
<form>
<input type="button" value="this is a styled text button" style="color:#fff;">
</form>
```

Is something like this possible to modify so only parts of the text in value will be affected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a span as others hav suggested. I would however completely avoid using inline css with the `style` attribute. Instead use classes. Its hard to recommend how exactly to apply the CSS without knowing the context of the usage but the following would be an example:

HTML:

```
<button class="starred">Title <span>*</span></button>
```

CSS:

```
button.starred span { color: #f00; }
```

Comment: I think I should have written some further information in my question. I can't use <button> because I'm not working with the html directly but through drupals form api. And so I need to use <input>. What I do is define a php array where you can specifiy the attributes of the <input>, so I wanted to get an idea of how that would look like in html(if it was possible) to know how to define the form array.

Comment: Then no... you will need to hook into the forms api and change the output. Regardless of how you apply the color.

Answer (score 2):

put that `*` in a span like

```
<button type="button">Title <span style="color:red;">*<span></button>
```

Update :

```
 <style>button>span{style="color:red;"}</style>
    <button type="button">Title <span>*<span></button>
```

Comment: @RasmusFranke No need to downvote because i prefer `button` over `input type="button"`

Comment: You steal my upvote, do you know about it? You have changed your incorrect answer to mine

Comment: @Random I commented and downvoted in error since I thought your solution wouldn't work, but I was in error so I upvoted instead and removed my comment.

Comment: This will do what the OP wants but inline styles with the `style` attribute are to be avoided. Only in extremly specific cases do they ever make sense to use. From the information given, this is not one of those cases.

Comment: I agree 100% but the main work here was to tell how to change the color instead of improving performance

Comment: @Random: Not really a performance thing from my perspective... its a maintainability thing. What if someone needs to change these all to `#0f0` later on? I mean one can do find and replace, but thats jsut silly when it could have been changed in a single place (ie. the CSS file).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `<input type="button"/>` you can use `<button>` tag,and style its label:

```
<button>Title<span style="color:#f00">*</span></button>
```

Comment: @RasmusFranke I have added earlier,before your comment

Comment: @RasmusFranke Why did you upvote Random's answer? it was pure copy-paste from my answer

Comment: @Engineer if you answer before 10 second then it does not mean that everybody is copying from you

Comment: @Random Not everybody,only *you*. You have seen my answer, and changed your incorrect answer to mine.

Comment: I would be in good mood to downvote this for whining, but I have too good manners for that. Is this forum here about fighting over aqn upvote and a few points for the personal profile, or helping other people with their problems. But if your are really dependent on that points, because you need to buy your food from it, then tell me, then I will give you an upvote.

Comment: @SvenBieder I do understand, that I can't prove,that what Random did, is just a plagiarism. Yes, you're right,that the goal of all(or probably the most) stackers to help others.But it should be *transparent*, who really helped. If you have *such good* manners,then you should be against of plagiarism,or I am wrong? I don't want your upvote(if I would want,I could make the fake upvotes by some other accounts,and I could 'buy food'[sarcasm] as much,as I need). I only want, that things must be in their correct places,and the upvote is earned by the person,who really deserves that.That's all.

Comment: @Random But what you are talking about is, if your answer is the accepted one or not. That is so or so very subjective, because chosen by a human. And the upvotes are chosen by all readers. So then you must say the readers are unfair, because they don't upvote 2 answers that say in the end the same, just using other words. That's life buddy, hard but unfair. Sometimes you lose, sometimes the others win.

Comment: @SvenBieder Don't tell me,that the life is hard and unfair.I do know about it very well. I don't understand your initiative for protecting Random,in such case,when you don't know about the facts of this question!! Are you and Random relatives?

Comment: @SvenBieder Do you understand, that Random is not so active for protecting his(her) 'answer',when I insist,that he(or she) copy-pasted my answer? That means,he(or she) feels that I am right.

Comment: @Engineer you can see my edit history of answer by clicking on the **edited** and tell me where i have copied you

Comment: @Random The editing history does not keep changes, if they are done less than 5 minutes after you firstly post your answer. You have done your copy-paste during that period.

Comment: @Engineer ok tell me what was my answer before my edit,i really have forgotten

Comment: @Random I don't see any logical reason to tell you that, but if you want I will remind you.Not sure what was that exactly,but it was something like a `<input type="button" style="color:red"/>`. But there was `<input type="button"/>` peace, I can assure you.Now did you remember?!!!!

Comment: WTF are you talking this answer was given by someone else and then he deleted that one.And now don't claim on me